# SQL - Making tables

Tags: java, mysql, arrays

Below is my code. I'm trying to get the two results on a same table but somehow I can only get them on separate table. Is there a way somehow to get both the tables to be linked together.

For example:

**Result1:**

Active Day

Year\\\Day\\\   Total

2014\\\1\\\\\\\ MY

**and**

**Result2:**

Timing

Year\\\Month\\\   Total

2014\\\12\\\\\\\\\ SG

**to**

Active Day\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\ Timing

Year\\\Day\\\  Total\\\\\\\\\\Month\\\  Total

2014\\\1\\\\\\\ MY\\\\\\\\\\\\\12\\\\\\\\\ SG

```
    public static String Summary() {

            String strResult="", result1="", result2=""
            Connection conn = null;

            try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
                String sql;             
                Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
                Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url);   
                Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
                sql = "EXECUTE GEOIP.dbo.CF_VIEW_DAILY_STAT'"+yesterdayDate()+"';";
                CallableStatement cstmt = connection.prepareCall(sql);  
                boolean hasMoreResultSets = cstmt.execute();  

          if (!hasMoreResultSets) {
                //System.out.println("The first result is not a ResultSet.");
                return strResult;
              } 

//First Result
                       ResultSet rs = cstmt.getResultSet();
                       result1 = "<table cellpadding='2' cellspacing='0' border='1'><tbody>"
                    + "<tr class='title1'><td colspan='4'>Active Day</td></tr>"
                    + "<tr class='title2'><td class='v_date' style='text-align:left'>Date</td><td class='v_number'>Day (s)</td><td class='v_number'>Country / Total</td><td class='v_number'>Active Count</td>" 
                    + "</tr>";

            while (rs.next()) {     
                result1 += "<tr>"
                        + "<td id='col1row1' class='v_date'>" + rs.getString("StatDt") + "</td><td class='v_number'>" + String.format("%,d", rs.getInt("ActiveDay")) 
                        + "</td><td class='v_number'>" + rs.getString("Country") + "</td><td class='v_number'>" + String.format("%,d", rs.getInt("ActiveCnt")) + "</td>"
                        +"</tr>";
            }       
            result1 += "</tbody></table><br/><br/>";
            rs.close();

//Second Result                
                hasMoreResultSets = cstmt.getMoreResults();
                if (!hasMoreResultSets) {
                //System.out.println("The first result is not a ResultSet.");
                return strResult;
              }
            ResultSet rs = cstmt.getResultSet();    
            result2 = "<table cellpadding='2' cellspacing='0' border='1'><tbody>"
                    + "<tr class='title1'><td colspan='3'>Conversion</td></tr>"
                    + "<tr class='title2'><td class='v_date'>Date</td><td class='v_number'>NRU</td>"
                    + "<td class='v_number'>NRU_Play</td>" 
                    + "</tr>"; 
            while (rs.next()) {                     
                result2 += "<tr>"
                        +  "<td class='v_date'>"+ rs.getString("StatDt") + "</td><td class='v_number'>" + String.format("%,d", rs.getInt("NRU"))
                        + "</td><td class='v_number'>" + String.format("%,d", rs.getInt("NRU_Play"))
                        + "</tr>";
            }           
            result2 += "</tbody></table><br/><br/>";            
            rs.close();     
            cstmt.close();
            connection.close();

                    } catch (SQLException se) {
               // Handle errors for JDBC
               se.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
               // Handle errors for Class.forName
               e.printStackTrace(); 
            }       

                strResult = result1 + result2;
                System.out.print(strResult);    
                return strResult;   
      }
```

How do I possibly get them on the same row, like linking them together [ignoring the year because it's the same]. Any help? I'm new to SQL here.

Comment: try to use unions on your view `CF_VIEW_DAILY_STAT`

Comment: How can I do that? Any examples?

Answer (score 0):

**Suggestions**:

- Create a common java object to store data read from both result sets.
- Read first result set and fill the data object.
- Read next result set and fill the data object with rest of fields.
- Now loop through the data object to that many number of items filled
  with.
- Construct the html `'tr'` and `'td'` to fill in each row as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `CF_VIEW_DAILY_STAT` view and get all the data in single resultset

For Example

```
SELECT Year1,Day1,Total1
FROM @ActiveDay
UNION
SELECT Month1,Total1
FROM @Timing
```

for the example i have changed the columns names because you are using reserved keyword in example.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that, I will try it but since I am kind of new to it. I would probably take some time

Answer (score 0):

use two different prepared or callable statements and combine the two different resultsets obtained.

String str=rs.getString(1) + " "+rs.getString(2);

Comment: Is this not how you do it?  

strResult = result1 + result2;
                System.out.print(strResult);    
                return strResult;   


Can you explain to me how? Please and thank you

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: String str=rs.getString(1) + " "+rs.getString(2);